# Connect to mysql using promise-mysql in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, typescript

I have a project in NoseJS and Typescript in which I am creating a generic mysql method using the `promise-mysql` module.

This is my `mysql-connect.ts` file:

```
import { databaseKeys } from '../models/mysql.models'
import getProperty from '../properties/properties.json'
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');
import * as logger from 'winston';

const keys_database: databaseKeys = {
    socket: getProperty.mysql.port,
    host: getProperty.mysql.host,
    user: getProperty.mysql.user,
    pass: getProperty.mysql.password,
    db: getProperty.mysql.database
}

const pool = mysql.createPool(keys_database);

pool.getConnection()
    .then((connection: any) => {
        pool.releaseConnection(connection);
        logger.info(`DB is Connected - ${keys_database.db}`);
    }).catch(function (err: any) {
        logger.error('Database Error: ' + err);
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            logger.error('Database connection was closed');
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            logger.error('Database has too many connections');
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            logger.error('Database connection was refused');
        }
    });

export default pool;
```

This is the `method` from where I call mysql to perform a query:

```
import * as logger from 'winston';
import * as getProperty from '../json/product.json';
import pool from '../../generic/utils/mysql-config'

import { ListProductBatchModel, ResultMsg } from '../models/listProduct.models';

export class ListProductBatchUtils {

    public async getDataProduct(codProduct: string): Promise<ListProductBatchModel> {

        try {

            let selectTest: string = `
                select * from test_bbdd.cli
            `;

            let query = await pool.query(selectTest);

            logger.info('getDataProduct()')
            return Promise.resolve(query);
            
        } catch (error) {
            logger.info(JSON.stringify(error));
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    }
}
```

**Upgrade:**

I have tried to change the version of the `promise-mysql` package to `3.3.1` and now it connects.
The problem is that now it shows an access error but the credentials are fine because I have tried the connection in another separate code and it works:

This is the new error:

```
[winston] Attempt to write logs with no transports {"message":"Database Error: Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)","level":"error"}
```

This is the old connection I have:

```
const mysql = require('promise-mysql');

export class connectBBDD {

    public async base() {

        const pool = mysql.createPool({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: '3030',
            user: 'root',
            password: 'root',
            database: 'test_bbdd'
        });
    
        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            if (err) throw err;
          
            connection.query('select * from cli', function (error, results) {
              console.log(results);
              if (error) throw error;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This is what it returns:

```
[ RowDataPacket { id: 7, name: 'test1', phone: null },
  RowDataPacket { id: 8, name: 'test2', phone: 111 }]
```